# How to prevent script loading from the cache [Angular]

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, browser-cache

I've created an Angular application. My application loads scripts from the server, but after the first run, as usual it takes scripts from the cache. I was using modern browsers but my tech leads want me to make it compatible with legacy browser as well. So, I'm using Internet Explorer 11 for now. I added some polyfills and got the application running:

```
/*******************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

But our requirement says that the application should fetch scripts from the server every single time the page loads. This is my network screenshot:
[image]
Obviously I cannot (or should not) say to our customers to manually disable their browser cache. Is there any way I can prevent this for IE 11 only or for all browsers from my code? Is it even doable? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command `ng build --outputHashing=bundles`. It creates the unique name of compiled files - with hashes. It solves the caching issue.

Documentation is [here](https://angular.io/cli/build)

And it does not matter which browser user uses

Comment: Ok dmk, I did not get any answer better than yours. So, for now I'm accepting this. I'll come back to you in case some help is required.